# No emulator images (avds) found-ionic cordova run android

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

I keep getting the error below anytime i try to run "ionic cordova run android" on my ionic project. I have an AVD installed and when i open it in android studio and run my app it actually launches. But if i don't manually launch the AVD i get this error. please help.

Built the following apk(s): 
        /Users/Samoyekeye/Desktop/Ionic Apps/klick/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Samoyekeye/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator
No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: /Users/Samoyekeye/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: /Users/Samoyekeye/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver

Comment: yes this actually happens when you'll run the first time or without opening the virtual device because there is no devices currently connected you can check this by typing "adb devices" in the terminal it will list the connected devices. But when you open the AVD manully then it gets connected and your app gets deployed on it

Comment: typing adb devices gives an empty list if i don't manually launch the avd. What i want is to be able to automatically lauch the AVD with " ionic cordova run android" from my terminal like it should.